# How to enable multiple ports on aws(ec2) windows instance for hosting multiple websites

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to enable multiple ports for hosting multiple websites.

for example: 123.34.56.90:80
123.34.56.90:81
123.34.56.90:82

I am successfully hosting the website on 123.34.56.90:80, but unable to access the website that I tried to host on others ports(but I can access locally).

[I have attached the inbound image as well for aws-group secuirty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/679e1.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the security group attached to the EC2 instance whether these ports are whitelisted?

Comment: No I did not, I am actually new to AWS so I don't know where to check

Comment: Select the EC2 instance and check its attached security group (Click on the link and edit the ports)

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately did not work for me.

Comment: Port 81 and 82 will need opening in windows firewall. IIS adds port 80 automatically.

Comment: I did not found any way to access port in aws publicly but when I had bind with hostname. It works, so I decided to with it.